# Pyomo DAE toolbox cannot discretize the domain appropriately

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm using Pyomo DAE toolbox to solve a partial differential equation and the domain length of one independent variable (say m.x) is very small (like 1e-6).

It seems to me that the DAE toolbox cannot discretize the domain appropriately because the discretized m.x only had 2 points (I used ContinuousSet.get_finite_elements() method to check that) even I specified 10 finite element points in the option (see code below).

```
m.x = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0, 1e-6))

disc=TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
disc.apply_to(m, nfe=10, wrt=m.x, scheme='BACKWARD')
```

I increased the upper bound of **m.x** as

```
m.x = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0, 1e-5))
```

and tried to discretize it again. This time I got 10 points in the x domain.

However, when I increased the number of finite element points as

```
m.x = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0, 1e-5))
disc.apply_to(m, nfe=100, wrt=m.x, scheme='BACKWARD')
```

the returned discretized domain x still had 10 points.

I want to know if there is a 1e-6 tolerance or limitation for DAE toolbox. If there is, how can I customize this value?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Bethany Nicholson is the developer most familiar with Pyomo.DAE. You may want to consider scaling your continuous set so that it is not so narrowly bounded, because you may run into issues with solvers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is currently a limit on the domain length. The discretization transformation currently rounds new discretization points to 6 decimal points. This is because I was seeing issues where the same discretization point was being added multiple times because of slight differences in floating point round off. As @QtotheC mentioned, the best solution would be to modify your scaling so that the bounds on the ContinuousSet are around (0,1).

The number of decimal points to include is not currently an option that can be modified by the user but you can always go into the source code and change the number [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/dae/misc.py#L42) and [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/dae/misc.py#L78).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful!